# Python authorization

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I need to write a script that is included in the personal account of my Internet provider and transmits information about the current balance.

At the moment I am stuck at the time of authorization. I found and edited such a script for myself:

```
import requests

url = 'https://bill.tomtel.ru/login.html'

USERNAME, PASSWORD, = 'mylogin', 'mypass'

resp = requests.get(url, auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD))

r = requests.post(url)

print(r.content)
```

But this does not help to pass authorization...

I can enter this link through a browser and go to a page of this type:

```
https://bill.tomtel.ru/fastcom/!w3_p_main.showform?FORMNAME=QFRAME&CONFIG=CONTRACT&SID=BLABLABLA&NLS=WR
```

I can go through browser authorization through both links, but why can't I do this through a script?

Please help with this.

Comment: Try this using post instead.  payload= {'USERNAME': USERNAME,'PASSWORD':PASSWORD} requests.post(url, data=payload) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://bill.tomtel.ru/signin.php'

USERNAME = input('Enter your username: ')
PASSWORD = input('Enter your password: ')
d = {
'USERNAME' : USERNAME,
'PASSWORD' : PASSWORD,
'FORMNAME' : 'QFRAME'}

session = requests.Session()

resp = session.post(url, data=d).text
if not '<TITLE>' in resp:
    print('Incorrect username or password!')
    quit()
print('Logging in ... ')
for line in resp.split('\n'):
    if 'location' in line:
        red = 'https://bill.tomtel.ru/fastcom/!w3_p_main.showform%s' % line.replace(' if (P>0) self.location.replace("', '').replace('");', '')
if not red:
    print('An error has occured')
    quit()
print('Redirecting to %s' % red)
page = session.get(red).text

print('')
print('          MAIN PAGE')
print(page)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207968/discussion-on-answer-by-ethical-hacker-minh-python-authorization).

Answer (score 1):

Your browser probably has a session token/cookie stored and that is why you can access it through the browser. There are a couple issues here:

1. It looks like you need to login to the site first -- through a `POST` method, not a `GET`. The `GET` is what loads the page. But once you submit the form it's going to do a `POST` request.
2. Actually, using `requests` to login to a site is not as easy as it looks. Usually you have to find the url it's `post`ing to (examine the developer toolbar to see the url), and you often have to pass information **in addition to** your username/password, such as a csrf token, a cookie, or something else.
3. I would suggest using a browser-automator for this, perhaps something like [`selenium Webdriver`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html). It makes logging into a site much simpler than using HTTP in a raw request, as it emulates a browser. I would suggest this -- it's much simpler and faster!

Another thing to note: `auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD)` is not quite the username/password in the form (it's something else) but I don't think understanding that is too relevant to what you're trying to do.

---

Here is the url and required form data to log in:

[image]

Comment: I double-up on the suggestion of using Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: I will keep this in mind, but I will leave it as a last resort. It can manage to get by in the usual way.